# How to stop position update, when pause button is pressed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have this code to make the particles follow my b2body object:

```
-(void)updateMagicFruitParticlePosition:(ccTime)dt{

    if (!gameManager.isPaused) {

         magicFruitParticle.position = especialObject.ccPosition;
    }
    else
       [self unschedule:_cmd];
}
```

The code works, but when the pause button is pressed and the player restarts the game, it crashes. Theoretically it should stop once the button was pressed, but it happens to be in the middle of the update even when the method has unscheduled.

The code below is what happens when the pause button is pressed:

```
-(void)pauseGame:(id)sender{

    if (!gameManager.isPaused ) {

        gameManager.isPaused = YES;

        [gameManager pauseAllSoundEffects];
        [gameManager pauseBackgroundMusic];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

        pauseLayer = [CCLayerColor layerWithColor:ccc4(0, 0, 0, 125) width:screenSize.width height:screenSize.height];
        pauseLayer.position = CGPointZero;
        [self addChild:pauseLayer z:kSecondLayer];

        backgroundPauseA = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"BackgroundPauseA"];
        backgroundPauseA.position = ccp(screenSize.width /2, screenSize.height /2);
        [self addChild:backgroundPauseA z:kSuperiorLayer];

        backgroundPauseB = [CCSprite spriteWithSpriteFrameName:@"BackgroundPauseB"];
        backgroundPauseB.position = ccp(screenSize.width /2, screenSize.height /2);
        [self addChild:backgroundPauseB z:kSuperiorLayer];

        [self pauseMenu]; 
    }
}
```

Is there any other way to make a particle effect follow an object or sprite? Or how can I fix it to work?

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks!

Comment: Can you give us brief code? that is , what is happening when paused button is pressed?

Comment: Yes, just one second!